# Installing Drupal 7 locally

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

When I run the install I get the same error:

> Your PHP installation is too old. Drupal requires at least PHP 5.2.5, or PHP 5.2.4 with the
>   htmlspecialchars security patch backported.

After a few hours of research it seems incredibly complicated to upgrade my version of php (currently 5.2.4 locally on my mac os x 10.4.11) so it appears I need to 'backport the htmlspecialchars security patch'.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction for how to do this? I can't seem to find any documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried one of the PHP packages from http://www.entropy.ch/software/macosx/php/ to upgrade your local PHP installation?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and just downloaded gave it a shot but it seems to want os x 10.5 to work. Back to looking for how to fit the security patch. I'll keep in touch if i can find out. Thanks again.

Comment: Please download the version for 10.4. You can search the page at the URL @Ian Oxley provided for the string "10.4" to find the correct download.